# Redirect before place order

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, redirect

I'm writing an extension. I hooked into event 'sales_order_place_before':

```
if (#condition) {  
    //redirect to cart
  $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
  $session->addError(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('error'));
  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
  Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
  exit;
}
```

When using firefox, in Network -> Response tab, I get shopping cart page with above message. But checkout page actually stays the same and the number of items in inventory are decreased.

Comment: why have you using sales_place_order?

Comment: because I needs to check #condition immediately after clicking Place Order button

Comment: hi! When you say the "above message" which message is that,  i dont quite understand, sorry